# How does Grunt minify or uglify IIFE?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, iife

In a standard `grunt serve` I use an IIFE around one of my directives like so:

```
    (function() {
  "use strict";

  angular.module('napiRest')
    .directive('componentStaffReport', ['$modal', 'ComponentStaffFactory', function ($modal, ComponentStaffFactory) {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
          componentId: '=componentId',
          linkableContent: '=linkableContent'
        },
        templateUrl: 'app/pages/report/component-staff/component-staff-popup.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
          ComponentStaffFactory.componentId = scope.componentId;
          var modalInstance = null;
          scope.open = function () {
            modalInstance = $modal.open({
              templateUrl: 'ComponentStaffModal.html',
              controller: 'ComponentStaffingCtrl',
              size: 'lg',
              backdrop: true,
              windowClass: 'x-x-large-modal'
            });
            ComponentStaffFactory.modalInstance = modalInstance;
          };
        } //link
      }; //return
    }])
})();
```

This does not work when I then deploy using `grunt serve:dist`. I get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function`

However, when I remove the surrounding IIFE it works without error. Is this somehow caused by the way uglify or minifying happens in the grunt for dist?

Comment: What plugin are you using to minify your code? Have you tried looking at the portion of the minified code to see exactly what's throwing the error?

Comment: grunt doesn't minify anything by itself.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the issue was caused by a semicolon missing in another file. The other file was an angular controller with no semicolon at the end. When grunt uglifys the code it smooshed this file and the file above together creating its own sort of anonymous function, which of course was disliked by the compiler.